# Numpy random draw gives different results

Tags: python, numpy, random, uniform

I try to get 20 data points drawn from a random distribution. It's straightforward but two methods below give different results, despite the seed is the same.

**Method 1**

```
np.random.seed(1)
x1 = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=20)
y1 = np.random.uniform(low=20, high=80, size=20)
```

The result is:

```
x1 = [-1.65955991  4.40648987 -9.9977125  -3.95334855 -7.06488218 -8.1532281
 -6.27479577 -3.08878546 -2.06465052  0.77633468 -1.61610971  3.70439001
 -5.91095501  7.56234873 -9.45224814  3.4093502  -1.65390395  1.17379657
 -7.19226123 -6.03797022]
```

and

```
y1 = [68.04467412 78.09569454 38.80545069 61.53935694 72.58334914 73.67639981
 25.10265268 22.34328699 30.18982517 72.68855021 25.90081003 45.2664575
 77.47337181 51.9899171  61.51262684 38.93093786 61.19005566 70.07754031
 21.09729664 65.0086589 ]
```

**Method 2**

```
N = 20
np.random.seed(1)
points = [(np.random.uniform(-10,10), np.random.uniform(20,80)) for i in range(N)]
```

The result is:

```
[(-1.6595599059485195, 63.219469606529486), (-9.997712503653101, 38.13995435791038), (-7.064882183657739, 25.54031568612787), (-6.274795772446582, 40.73364362258286), (-2.0646505153866013, 52.32900404020142), (-1.6161097119341044, 61.11317002380557), (-5.910955005369651, 72.68704618345672), (-9.452248136041476, 60.22805061070413), (-1.6539039526574602, 53.5213897067451), (-7.192261228095324, 31.886089345092728), (6.014891373510732, 78.09569454316386), (-3.7315164368151432, 61.53935694015885), (7.527783045920767, 73.67639981023083), (-8.299115772604441, 22.343286993972942), (-6.6033916087086215, 72.68855020576478), (-8.033063323338999, 45.26645750030313), (9.157790603010039, 51.98991709838103), (3.837542279009467, 38.93093786036378), (3.7300185536316732, 70.07754031384238), (-9.634234453116164, 65.00865889669805)]
```

Could anyone help with explaining the difference?

Comment: What does it mean by "methods below give different results"?? What result do you need? The first method returns a 1D list and the second returns a tuple list??

Comment: Most random number generators depend on the last generated value every time. You generate random numbers in different order, the results will naturally be different.

Comment: @FelixFilipi The results are the random numbers being generated by the codes. Since the seed is set to be the same in both methods, I thought the random numbers drawn from the same distribution would be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method first generates 20 numbers from the first distribution, followed by 20 numbers from the second distribution. In the second method, you alternate the distribution from which numbers are being generated. These methods do not generate corresponding numbers in the same order, so you should not expect to get the same results. Each time you generate a random number, the internal state of the generator changes, and that change affects all subsequent invocations of the generator, regardless of whether it is applied to the same distribution. `numpy.random` methods all use the same global internal state.

As an aside, NumPy recommends the use of `numpy.random.Generator` methods instead of `numpy.random` or `numpy.random.RandomState` methods (see [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html)).